# UWP MapControl does not draw MapPolyline and other elements on Surface Pro 4

Tags: windows-10, uwp, surface

The same project compiled on the identical versions of Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 but on different hardware (Asus laptop and Surface Pro 4) produces different results: some elements (like MapPolyline and borders of MapPolygon) are not drawn along with the whole streets outlines and such (see the attached screenshots)

**Expected behavior**
[image]

**Problematic behavior**

[image]

Does anybody experience similar behavior and/or know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same bug as reported here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-win_maps/windows-10-maps-app-sometimes-does-not-show-the/7183916a-9567-4d49-ab92-297eec8737ab?auth=1 Microsoft is working on a fix...